# Pandas - adding new string column results in NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I've had some trouble assigning a new column in a Pandas dataframe - I have got it working, but want to understand why it happens;

When I first tried to assign the ID to a string, the result was NaN..

```
df = pandas.json_normalize(data)
all_per = pandas.DataFrame()
for person in peopleList:
    all_per['id'] = person
    all_per['name'] = df['results.(id:'+person+').localizedFirstName'] + ' ' + \
                      df['results.(id:'+person+').localizedLastName']
```

Results:

```
    id          name
0  NaN    Adam Smith
```

However if I move the ID assignment down a bit, it works..

```
df = pandas.json_normalize(data)
all_per = pandas.DataFrame()
for person in peopleList:
    all_per['name'] = df['results.(id:'+person+').localizedFirstName'] + ' ' + \
                      df['results.(id:'+person+').localizedLastName']
    all_per['id'] = person
```

Results:

```
           name          id
0    Adam Smith    FQR4bL_80K
```

This took up a lot of my time, and I have no idea why it happened? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a scalar value. You have to enclose `person` into a list:

```
df = pandas.json_normalize(data)
all_per = pandas.DataFrame()
for person in peopleList:
    all_per['id'] = [person]  # <- HERE
    all_per['name'] = df['results.(id:'+person+').localizedFirstName'] + ' ' + \
                      df['results.(id:'+person+').localizedLastName']
```

Output:

```
>>> all_per

           id        name
0  FQR4bL_80K  Adam Smith
```

Comment: Oh thank you - right, yes I'm adding a scalar value which doesn't make sense as I can have multiple people in the list.. I'll use `all_per.append` . Much appreciated

Comment: This is not the best strategy. You should collect your data into python data structure (list or dict) then merge them with `pd.concat` at the end of your loop.